# Django - random file in jquery in template

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am making a django webapp. On the homepage, have some divs where i want to display random images from my database that changes periodically (that is each div gets a random image from database every few seconds). The jquery for this uses some for loops to achieve this. I have passed the filelist in my views.py file and i am able to retrieve imagelist in my template. But when i put {{ filelist | random }} in my jquery, it takes the same file name every time in every loop. How do i solve this situation?

Let me know what extra information should i provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the "random" django filter will return one object from a list, that's why only one object is available. Second, jquery doesn't work with django templating engine directly, it works with what comes out of the templating engine. You have to remember that django template tags and filters are rendered server side and once it's rendered, it's done, sent to the client... and doesn't change until you make another request.

If "filelist" is your context value then you can have jquery code that acts on a javascript array. You can do something like this: (assuming all values in filelist are strings)

```
var js_array = [{% for f in filelist %}"{{ f }}",{% endfor %}];
```